# Construction of coupled inductors with lesser coupling factor

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, magnetics

Most SMPS use coupled magnetics of various kinds. While designing buck/boost and their isolated versions, construction of the coupled magnetic element is straight forward. In many of these converters the issue of discontinuous current (both on the input and output exist) . I came across [literature](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/548609) which claim zero ripple using coupled inductors. The results are fascinating to say the least

However it requires the need of coupled inductors with coupling factors <1. Designs specifically mention critical values to be around 0.6. I don't seem to find any links for construction of such inductors.

How are such coupled inductors constructed? (what type of cores, winding detail etc.,)

Comment: Take an E core and wind coils on the outer limbs.

Comment: I don't understand the physics of this. Intuitively, it seems that this method of construction would provide a fixed coupling factor

Comment: Yes, a fixed coupling factor of less than 1. You didn't say you needed a variable coupling factor did you? Anyway, your on your own on this because you don't appear to recognize the importance of formally accepting answers to some of your previous questions raised nor upvoting good answers to some of your questions.

Comment: My apologies Andy, I seem to have misunderstood the platform. I was under the impression that up-votes are to be done by the community. Will get to rectify these

Comment: You have the reputation to make upvotes to any answer and you always have had the ability to formally accept any particular answer to any question you have raised.

Comment: There seems to be some issue with my mail settings. I am not receiving any mail alerts for answers to queries.

Answer (score 1):

A unity coupling factor k is a perfect nonexistent transformer. Real transformers have magnetizing inductance in parallel and leakage inductance in series. So if k is too high you can place some fixed inductances around your coupled coil to make k arbitrarily low. When designing a transformer there are known tricks like air core, magnetic shunts, bucking windings, etc. Remember that low k transformers tend to be more lossy.